# Simple html cache for Ubuntu Server 14.10

Tags: 14.10, cache, caching

Which is the best system for html cache in Ubuntu Server? I have some sites in hosting on my dedicated server.

I installed and set APC, I enable the cache of Apache.

The sites are all made in WordPress.

I tried to install Varnish, but I would not change the ports of the system.

And i don't like to cange or integrate DNS system.

There is a simple, safe and unobtrusive system that helps to increase the performance of my server?

How do you implement it?

APT-cacher? How is it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480304/how-to-set-http-headers-for-cache-control

Comment: Thank you! Yes but for install a system like Varnish (more simple)? In php, i just added this infomration by php editor or plugins for WordPress.

Comment: Google is your friend... https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=tuning+Apache+cache&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: Ahhahaha...right! And think that I am a SEO specialist!!!ahhahhhaa

Comment: I'm just a generalist.....

Answer (score 1):

How about [Memcached](http://memcached.org/)

Easy Setup:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server php5-mysql php5 php5-memcached memcached
```

Check that it has been installed by searching for it:

```
ps aux | grep memcache
```

Or, To see the memcache stats

```
echo "stats settings" | nc localhost 11211
```

You need more detail? Read this from [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-memcache-on-ubuntu-14-04)